# Return Value from External PHP Class for Use in If Condition

Tags: php, oop

Still learning about OOP Programming, but am testing with [proxy-scraper](https://github.com/vantoozz/proxy-scraper)

Here's my `test.php` script that I'm looking to return a variable from a class in an external php file:

```
<?php

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
use Vantoozz\ProxyScraper\HttpClient\GuzzleHttpClient;
use Vantoozz\ProxyScraper\Scrapers;

$scraper = new Scrapers\HideMyIpScraper($httpClient);

foreach ($scraper->get() as $proxy2) {

    $proxyexplode = explode(':', $proxy2);
    $ipv4proxy = (string)$proxyexplode [0];
    $portproxy = (int)$proxyexplode [1];

    $proxy = new Proxy(new Ipv4($ipv4proxy), new Port($portproxy));

}
```

Now, this interacts with the file on my localhost `Scrapers/HideMyIpScraper.php`. The entire php file can be viewed [here](https://github.com/vantoozz/proxy-scraper/blob/master/src/Scrapers/HideMyIpScraper.php)

Whenever `$proxy` is run in my foreach loop, this is called:

```
/**
 * @return \Generator|Proxy[]
 * @throws \Vantoozz\ProxyScraper\Exceptions\ScraperException
 */
public function get(): \Generator
{
    try {
        $html = $this->httpClient->get($this->makeUrl());
    } catch (HttpClientException $e) {
        throw new ScraperException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

    foreach ($this->extractData($html) as $item) {

        $countrycode = $item['c']['f'];
        var_dump($countrycode);

        if (!\is_array($item)) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            yield $this->makeProxy($item);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I added to that above was `$countrycode = $item['c']['f'];`

What I'm trying to do is retrieve this value in my `test.php` in the `foreach` loop, so it's soemthing like this

```
$array = array();
foreach ($scraper->get() as $proxy2) {
    $proxy = new Proxy(new Ipv4($ipv4proxy), new Port($portproxy));
    // $countrycode is var_dumped here from `HideMyIpScraper.php`
    if ($countrycode == 'us') {
        $array[] = $proxy2;
    }
```

But of course `$countrycode` is in the external function in a different php file, so this is invalid and throws out an error.

I've tried stuff like `return $countrycode` but this breaks the `foreach ($this->extractData($html) as $item) {` loop after the first iteration.

How can I get the `$countrycode` variable in my `test.php` script for conditional logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an array containing the proxy and the country code from your generator.

```
public function get(): \Generator
{
    try {
        $html = $this->httpClient->get($this->makeUrl());
    } catch (HttpClientException $e) {
        throw new ScraperException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }

    foreach ($this->extractData($html) as $item) {

        $countrycode = $item['c']['f'];
        var_dump($countrycode);

        if (!\is_array($item)) {
            continue;
        }
        try {
            yield array($this->makeProxy($item), $countrycode);
        } catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Then split up the result in your `foreach` loop.

```
$array = array();
foreach ($scraper->get() as $val) {
    list ($proxy2, $countrycode) = $val;
    $proxy = new Proxy(new Ipv4($ipv4proxy), new Port($portproxy));
    // $countrycode is var_dumped here from `HideMyIpScraper.php`
    if ($countrycode == 'us') {
        $array[] = $proxy2;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Surprised the answer was so easy, with just a one or two line modification.  Would have taken me ages if I ever even would have thought to try - thank you!